# Including PHP file in Wordpress Template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, themes

As of right now I have this code in one of my templates on my Wordpress theme.

```
// blah blah

        <div class="content">

            <?php include_once( 'http://www.website.com/new/file.php?variable=1' ); ?>

        </div>

// blah blah
```

Now, it will load everything in this template except this php include! It will load the sidebar which is included above the /* blah blah */ and it will load the footer, navigation, etc.

When I Inspect Element on Google Chrome it shows this:

```
<div class="content">

       (it's empty)

</div>
```

Please help me if you know what I'm doing wrong! Thank you!

Comment: Well, what does that PHP file output when you open it in a browser?

Comment: Instead of using include-like functions, grab a content from URL and echo it `echo file_get_contents('http://www.website.com/new/file.php?variable=1');`

Comment: Is your website on `http://www.website.com` (i.e. the same domain as the included file)? If not, you should use file_get_contents or something.

Answer (score 4):

`include` and `require` don't take URLs. They take server filepaths. Try this:

```
<?php include_once(ABSPATH.'/new/file.php'); ?>
```

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention that query strings cannot be included in filepaths. If a query string is necessary for proper loading, consider loading the page with all necessary query variables in your current URL, loading the part using an iframe, or using `file_get_contents()`

**Iframe:**

```
<iframe src="http://www.website.com/new/file.php?variable=1"></iframe>
```

**file_get_contents()**

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('http://www.website.com/new/file.php?variable=1'); ?>
```

Comment: Warning: include_once(/home/username/public_html/new/file.php?variable=1) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/username/public_html/new/wp-content/themes/theme1/template_home.php on line 30

That's what I get.. I know the files there because I can get to /new/file.php?variable=1 in browser and it works..

Edit: works when I remove the ?variable=1 at the end of it.. but I need that variable there?

Comment: Look at the path. Why is it pointing to /new/wp-content/themes/ when you're looking for /new/file.php?

Comment: I have no idea.. but I works when I remove '?variable=1'. I'm thinking it says that to say where the source file is.. because my template source is in that template (template_home.php)

Comment: Once again, it's not a URL, so query strings can't be passed to it. If the query string is necessary, have you considered using an iframe? If it's not necessary, then it seems as if your problem is solved, no?

Comment: @ChadCardiff View the edit. I've thrown out a few other options for you if you're still having trouble.

Comment: It is necessary, but an iframe is not the best solution. Thank you though!

Comment: Then be sure to have the page load with all necessary query variables. That's my only advice. An iframe is a rather hackish way of doing it, but without knowing what's in that file, I'm throwing out as many options for you as I can. Good luck.